# How to Fix "End of File Expected" JSON Settings VS Code?

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code

```
{
    
"workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+"

}

{ }
   
"name": "C++ Launch",
    
"type": "cppdbg",

    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "customLaunchSetupCommands": [
      { "text": "target-run", "description": "run target", "ignoreFailures": false }
    ],
    "launchCompleteCommand": "exec-run",
    "linux": {
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
    },
    "osx": {
      "MIMode": "lldb"
    },
    "windows": {
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGw\\bin\\gdb.exe"
    }
  }
```

Comment: BTW. why you have { } in your json and also last } dont have { at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have posted is not valid json.  You've got several typos including:

- An empty empty set of curly braces `{}` on line 7, followed by several key value attribute pairs not enclosed in curly braces.

This might be closer to what you want:

```
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
  "name": "C++ Launch",
  "type": "cppdbg",
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
  "stopAtEntry": false,
  "customLaunchSetupCommands": [
    {
      "text": "target-run",
      "description": "run target",
      "ignoreFailures": false
    }
  ],
  "launchCompleteCommand": "exec-run",
  "linux": {
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
  },
  "osx": {
    "MIMode": "lldb"
  },
  "windows": {
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGw\\bin\\gdb.exe"
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this really helped. i get it now.